# Telegram Authentication using TLSharp

Tags: c#, telegram

I try to develop a client for Telegram using [TLSharp v 0.1.0.209](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) that does nothing but receiving messages and running some simple logic on their content

My code currently looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TLSharp.Core;

namespace TelegramBot
{
    public sealed class Service
    {
        private TelegramClient client;

        public Service()
        {
            this.client = new TelegramClient(etc.Constants.AppApiId, etc.Constants.AppApiHash);
        }

        public async void Connect()
        {
            await this.client.ConnectAsync();
        }

        public async void Authenticate(String phoneNumber)
        {
            var hash = await client.SendCodeRequestAsync(phoneNumber);

            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }

            var code = "<code_from_telegram>"; // you can change code in debugger

            var user = await client.MakeAuthAsync(phoneNumber, hash, code);
        }
    }
}
```

and I call it like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Service bot = new Service();

    bot.Connect();
    bot.Authenticate(etc.Constants.PhoneNumber);

    Debugger.Break();
}
```

However, I get a 'NullPointerException' when calling 'SendCodeRequestAsync'. How can I fix/ approach this? The number is provided in this format '+12223334444'

[image: NullPointerException]

Comment: Why `async void`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `async void` methods can't be awaited. Any exceptions thrown by them can't be caught either. They are only meant to be used in event handlers or event-handler-like methods.

The equivalent of a `void` method is `async Task`, not `async void`.

In this case, the methods should be changed to :

```
    public async Task Connect()
    {
        await this.client.ConnectAsync();
    }

    public async Task Authenticate(String phoneNumber)
    {
    //...
    }
```

And `Main()` should change to :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Service bot = new Service();

    bot.Connect().Wait();
    bot.Authenticate(etc.Constants.PhoneNumber).Wait();

    Debugger.Break();
}
```

or, even better :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Service bot = new Service();

    Authenticate(bot).Wait();

    Debugger.Break();
}

static async Task Authenticate(Service bot)
{
    await bot.Connect();
    await bot.Authenticate(etc.Constants.PhoneNumber);
}
```